# Multiverse explanation of fine tuning of cosmic constants

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, multiverse, fine-tuning

Physicists proposed the idea of multiverses to explain extraordinary fine tuning of the cosmic constant and physical laws which is essential for rise of life on earth.

> Is there any experiment that can test the validity of multiverse hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

Almost by definition, everything that can influence us today is part of our universe. So something in another universe (roughly) cannot have any relevance to our universe today.

However, in some (very speculative) models, what is now in another universe might have influenced our universe a long time ago, and we might be able to find signatures of that in [cosmic microwave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background_radiation) or other cosmological observations.

Comment: What kind of observable past events would make us conclude that there are more than one universe?

Comment: One such example is the case of [cosmic bubble collisions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/observable-in-principle-signal-of-a-bubble-collision-in-eternal-inflation), when two (or more) universes collide. Here's a semi-random article about [looking for evidence](http://www.universetoday.com/87927/testing-the-multiverse-observationally/)

Comment: Sorry, This does not make any sense. If two universes can collide then are just part of one universe.

Comment: Well, what if they collided, but then got driven far away from each other due to the universe's accelerated expansion? So far (and moving away so fast) that no signal I send now will reach the "other universe" and vice versa.

Comment: You might find [this phy.SE thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27477/cosmic-bubble-collision) helpful.

Comment: "*what if [universes] collided, but then got driven far away from each other *" You do realize that a statement like this, when pertaining to different universes, makes no sense whatsoever? That there is no metric that would allow us to meaningfully talk about "universes being far from each other", since space and time is encapsulated in the universe? From there it is but a small step to the realization that the very idea of "multiple universes" is meaningless as a scientific statement. Those physicists who talk about this kind of material have lost their way, in a very tragic manner.

Comment: And, no, there is not, and cannot be any experiment that could validate the idea of "multiple universes". Thus, this idea has no place in physics, or any science for that matter.